# How SSO (authentication) and authorization will work if we have two Identity Servers?

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, identityserver3, keycloak

What permissions and roles will be used for authorization and authentication if we have two identity servers?

Example:
**ABC Product** is using Keycloak Identity server which has its own users, user roles, user groups, and permissions etc..

Now, another company wants to use same product and this company has its own Identity server. Now, we have to configure this ID Server to an Product ID server.

1. How SSO will work here?
2. Product will use its own Roles and Permissions or It will use newly configured ID Server user Roles and Permissions?
3. How the Users will be maintained? in both Identity server will have same Users?

Comment: What protocol do you want to use for SSO ? ex) OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0 and SAML 2.0

Comment: We are using OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 for authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with keycloak, so I only to write general stuff.

> How SSO will work here?

I think both servers can work as Identity server. For example, it is necessary to upload metadata into service provider (applications, you want to login) to use SAML. You can let users login to some SaaS applications with uploading metadata and then creating federation between Idp server and service provider servers.

> Product will use its own Roles and Permissions
>   or It will use newly configured ID Server user Roles and Permissions?

I guess first one is correct.

> How the Users will be maintained? in both Identity server will have
>   same Users?

If both identity servers used LDAP or AD, you should sync both users. Or, it's better to merge them into a new organization.

**EDIT**

- [active directory servers synchronization](https://serverfault.com/questions/245036/active-directory-servers-synchronization)

This link indicates how to sync an AD server to another one.

Comment: If both identity servers used LDAP or AD, you should sync both users. Or, it's better to merge them into a new organization.

We cannot merge them into a new organization, the new product is a subset of their existing ID server, So, in case if the employee left the company they will delete the user from their own ID server. 
The Same user should delete from the Product ID Server. --> How this we can achieve

Comment: I think it's impossible to complete your requirement with using default AD feature. Because you supposed a architecture "master-master" and it should track all CRUD(create/read/update/delete) operations for AD.

Answer (score 1):

if at all possible, the keycloak server should be configured to trust the other identity server as an external identity provider. Users logging in to keycloak then have the option to login through identity server. This is exactly the same as when you login to SO via Google.